# What are some notably difficult tapas yogis have performed in modern days?

Tags: yoga, saint

I just learned of Shivabalayogi's tapas of meditating for 23 hours a day for eight years. And 12 hours a day for two more years. That is the most notable tapas I have heard of. What are some other notable tapas that modern yogis have done?

Comment: Answers seeking 'greatest', 'most difficult', 'amazing' tapas will lead to opinion-based answers and are generally discouraged here. Please rephrase your question or it might be closed by the moderators. Please see [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/379/2995) for on-topic questions on this forum.

Comment: What is one person's tapas is not so to another. All tapas are relative. The greatest Tapas in this age is to always tell the truth. A person who tells the truth for 12 years cannot speak a lie and will realize God.

Answer (score 2):

Sri Ramana Maharishi meditated in a cellar-like temple called Pathala Lingam , which is a part of the Arunachala Temple ( A board to this effect, can still be found there. I have visited the temple).

http://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/ramana-maharshi/at-arunachala/

> He shifted  to an underground vault known as Patala Lingam, where the
>   sunlight never penetrated. Without moving he sat deeply absorbed in
>   the Self and was unaware of being bitten up by the ants and vermin
>   living there.
>
> he didn’t even realize when some devotees finally came, lifted him out
>   of the pit and brought him to the nearby Subrahmanya shrine. For about
>   two months he stayed in that shrine paying no attention to his bodily
>   needs.  To make him eat, food had to be forcefully put into his mouth.

[Similar accounts of Sri Ramakrishna](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OH1ABAAAQBAJ&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=sri%20ramakrishna%20nirvikalpa%20samadhi%20fed&source=bl&ots=--gglDs7pZ&sig=ixug_Y1iPur4PyUtcAa5Vb7CcSM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYrtrDnYnKAhUIB44KHR2IDBMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=sri%20ramakrishna%20nirvikalpa%20samadhi%20fed&f=false) are found in books about his years of spiritual effort.

[Swami Vivekananda's account of his meeting with one Pavahari Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavhari_Baba) is quite famous and is mentioned in the various biography books on Swami Vivekananda. Pavahari Baba is said to have not come out of his cave for five years.